# MPAndroidChart - removing old data points in real time chart

Tags: java, android, plot, mpandroidchart, real-time-data

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to create some real time plots of accelerometer data. It seems that memory usage continuously grows the longer you leave the app running so I tried to find a way to remove old data points once they are out of view of the charts scrolling window.

The problem is that once I hit the limit I set for the max number of points to keep/display, points are no longer added but the chart keeps scrolling. The size of my data remains constant (as it should as I'm both adding a new point and removing an old one every update), but no new data gets displayed in the chart anymore.

In my fragment, I'm creating the chart like this in `onCreateView`:

```
accChart = (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.accChart);
        accChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

        LineData data = new LineData();
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        accChart.setData(data);
```

Then I listen for accelerometer events using sensor manager, and add an entry every 100ms in `onSensorChanged`:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        sensor = event.sensor;

        curAccX = event.values[0];
        curAccY = event.values[1];
        curAccZ = event.values[2];

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);

        // only allow one update every POLL_FREQUENCY.
        if(diffTime > POLL_FREQUENCY) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            addEntry(curAccX, curAccY, curAccZ);
        }

    }
```

Then to add the entries in `addEntry` I'm doing this:

```
private void addEntry(float curAccX, float curAccY, float curAccZ){
        LineData data = accChart.getData();

        if (data != null) {

            ILineDataSet xData = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
            ILineDataSet yData = data.getDataSetByIndex(1);
            ILineDataSet zData = data.getDataSetByIndex(2);

            if (xData == null) {
                xData = createSetX();
                data.addDataSet(xData);
            }
            if (yData == null) {
                yData = createSetY();
                data.addDataSet(yData);
            }
            if (zData == null) {
                zData = createSetZ();
                data.addDataSet(zData);
            }

            // add a new x-value first
            data.addXValue(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            data.addEntry(new Entry(curAccX, xData.getEntryCount()), 0);
            data.addEntry(new Entry(curAccY, yData.getEntryCount()), 1);
            data.addEntry(new Entry(curAccZ, zData.getEntryCount()), 2);

            //This is where I remove the first entry for each series
            if (xData.getEntryCount() > MAX_POINTS_DISPLAYED){
                xData.removeFirst();
                yData.removeFirst();
                zData.removeFirst();
            }

            // let the chart know it's data has changed
            accChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // limit the number of visible entries
            accChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(MAX_POINTS_DISPLAYED);

            // move to the latest entry
            accChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount());
        }
    }
```

I think the problem lies in my usage of `removeFirst`. If I uncomment all those lines, data keeps getting plotted. If I uncomment `removeFirst` for only one of the series, that one gets plotted fine, but the other 2 are empty as I described above

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `data.notifyDataChanged()` directly after adding the entries.

Comment: That didn't seem to help. I added it after each call to `removeFirst`. I also tried adding `invalidate` after each entry but same issue

Comment: You should place it after the add methods!

Comment: added `data.notifyDataChanged()` after the add block, and then again after the remove block. The result is the same no matter where I add it